# Using Firebase Remote Config with disabled Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-remote-config

When using Firebase Remote Config in an Android app, Firebase Analytics needs to be added as a dependency since Firebase Remote Config depends on it. Because of that, I need to have Firebase Analytics in my build file. But because of GDPR rules, I need to have it disabled in some cases and for some versions of the app.

I am trying to find out if it's possible to use Firebase Remote Config with disabled Firebase Analytics (flag `firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated` set to `true`).
With Firebase Analytics disabled, will Remote Config still send some data to Firebase servers except Firebase Installation ID specified [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy#data_processing_information)?
Finally, will I still be able to target users by location and app version in Remote Config?

Answer (score 2):

yes you are still able to use remote config. I just tested it on my side by disabling analytics and changing parameter on remote config.

Also have a look at the documentation

> When you build an app that includes both Firebase Remote Config and
> Google Analytics, you gain the ability to understand your app users
> better and to respond to their needs more quickly. You can use
> Analytics audiences and user properties to customize your app for
> segments of your user base with flexibility and precision.
>
> Warning: To use audiences and user properties with Remote Config, you
> must enable Google Analytics data sharing for your project. In your
> app, you'll need to ensure Firebase Analytics is present and data
> collection is available as well.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/config-analytics

So analytics is only an addition and not mandatory for remote config to work :-)

Comment: I also tried that, and it also works for me. But I am not sure if I can still target new versions of the app if Firebase Analytics is not enabled. How will Remote Config know that there is a new app version? Or how Remote Config knows that the user is in some country without Firebase Analytics?

Comment: This I can't answer, sorry. But I'd guess that it isn't possible :(

Comment: @thehrlein can you please take a look into this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73545083/11560810)