# How to know remote config working in android firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-remote-config

I am learning firebase remote config. I am trying to set time interval to fetch value from firebase. I want to know that value is fetched or not. So how can I achieved this through in code?

```
object RemoteConfigFb {

    private val remoteConfig: FirebaseRemoteConfig by lazy {
        Firebase.remoteConfig
    }

    fun initialize() {
        val configSettings = remoteConfigSettings {
            minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds = 60 * 5 // 5 minutes
        }
        remoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings)
    }

    fun refreshConfig() {
        remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            logD("fetchAndActivate success: ${task.isSuccessful}")

            if (task.isSuccessful) {
               // welcome message
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling below method to button click

```
remoteConfig.getString("Welcome message")
```

I am getting new value in every 5 minutes. My main question is how to track that value is fetched or not and even I want to check fetch is fail or not. So how can I determine all this in this code. Thanks

Comment: You can get the last fetch status by calling `remoteConfig.info.lastFetchStatus`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
remoteConfig.info.lastFetchStatus
```

I am using above code to get status. Thanks @[ocos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8760805/ocos) for your great advice.